# How the new permission mechanism work for old apps?

Tags: android, android-permissions

In Android 6 and higher , the mechanism of catching permission is changed .
Now this is my question :
If an old app that is written 6 years ago for Android 2.3.3 and needs a high necessary permission ( for example reading from internal storage ) and in that time caught that permission by manifest file , now is installed on a new Android 8 device , what happens ? Does it crash ? If no , Why ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permission is automatically **granted** if it is declared in `AndroidManifest.xml` and the `targetSdkVersion` is less than 23.

Though Google PlayStore no longer accepts apps targeting API 25 or lower.

Answer (score 0):

check this documentation it's helpful

[Run Time Permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview)